# dojo Datagrid filter select that allows user to select from a list of values in the column

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dijit.layout, dojo.gridx

I m using dojo datagrid which contains 2 columns "name" and "age" , the requirement  is to provide the filtering option on the "name" column in the  datagrid. so that user can search and select his/her name  from the list of values ,by clicking on the header of the name column.
Is there any option that need to set  in layout  for the same.
can some one please help on this.

```
var layout = [
                          {field: "Name", name: "Name", width: '200px' },
                          {field: "Age", name: "Age", width: '100px' },

                          ];

            var resultStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore:new Memory({ data: [],idProperty:"id" }) });

            var dGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                store: resultStore,
                selectionMode: "none",
                autoHeight: true,
                structure: layout,
                sortInfo: 1,                        
                canSort: function(colIndex) {                       
                    return true;
                }                   
            });
```

Comment: use the dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter see here https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Filter.html 
you cann add it in plugins section

Comment: by default there is the .Filter plugin but, its suitable to use the grid.filter() an implement your own form of filter dissociated of the table

Comment: @Springer ,so it is not possible with datagrid it's only possible with enhancedGrid?

Comment: in my case I've alwyes used the [dojo dgrid](http://dgrid.io) component its not eperimental an have powerfull features , Describe here exactely what you wnat i'll try to reproduce an example of dgrid

Comment: @SpringerF all i need is filter in the datagrid header from wch user can select the value from header, my case i have two headers name and age. i need to provide filter in the name header where user can search and select his name form the list of names